# Python pandas .map saves only last edit

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas .map to edit a dataset as in the following code:

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].astype('category')
reg = df['Region']
cats = reg.cat.categories
ncats = len(cats)
n = len(os)

north = (...)
south = (...)
center = (...)
islands = (...)

d1 = {cats[i]:'South' for i in range(ncats) if cats[i] in south}
d2 = {cats[i]:'North' for i in range(ncats) if cats[i] in north}
d3 = {cats[i]:'Center' for i in range(ncats) if cats[i] in center}
d4 = {cats[i]:'Islands' for i in range(ncats) if cats[i] in islands}

df['Reg_cat'] = df['Region'].map(d1)
df['Reg_cat'] = df['Region'].map(d2)
df['Reg_cat'] = df['Region'].map(d3)
df['Reg_cat'] = df['Region'].map(d4)
df['Reg_cat'] = df['Reg_cat'].astype('category')
df['Reg_cat'].cat.categories
df['Reg_cat']
```

The code does work but it only applies the last .map request. So in this case it applies d4. If d1 is the last one it applies that one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: overwriting the values in each subsequent `map` call is what you're doing, you probably need `loc`

Comment: And how would I use that? The documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html is not really helping.

Comment: There is probably a much easier way to do what you are trying to achieve. Instead of asking about your attempted solution (XY problem) you should ask about your actual problem, along with input and expected output. You can *probably* get away with a single call to `.apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each successive `map` call replaces everything not inside the mapper with NaN.

Try building a single dictionary and passing that instead.

```
m = {'North' : north, 'South' : south, 'Center' : center, 'Islands', islands}    
d = {v2 : k for k, v in m.items() for v2 in v}

df['Reg_cat'] = df['Reg_cat'].map(d)
```

Note:

- you don't need `reg`
- you don't need `cats`
- you don't need `ncats`
- you also (not surprisingly) don't need `n`, whatever *that* is

Comment: Thanks, but using your code I get NaN for all entries

Comment: @ToTom My guess is you have trailing/leading spaces, or the like, either in `d` or in `df['Reg_cat']`.

Comment: @ToTom Either that, or you forgot to refresh your notebook and/or data.

Comment: df['Reg_cat'] should be empty and d is kinda the code you gave me... Sorry I'm quite new to data science

Comment: I'll try to refresh

Comment: @ToTom `df['Reg_cat']` should not be empty, that defeats the purpose of `map`

Comment: Infact, the mistake was that in the very first line there was df['Region'] instead of df['Reg_cat']. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are calling `df['Reg_cat'] = df['Region'].map(d#)` you are overwriting the value of `df['Reg_cat']`. If you'd like to keep all the values, consider adding them as separate columns.